# Undefined variable: mapleader

Tags: vim

I'm having a problem whereby no commands which involve the `<leader>` key seem to work.

```
:let mapleader
=> Undefined variable: mapleader
```

My `.vimrc` mentions `leader` three times. They're all references to function calls.

```
map <leader>n :call RenameFile()<cr>
map <leader>p :PromoteToLet<cr>
nnoremap <leader>. :call OpenTestAlternate()<cr>
```

Here's a [link to my .vimrc](https://github.com/dtuite/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc) on Github.

Anyone got any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: If `g:mapleader` is undefined `<Leader>` is expanded to `\\` which is mentioned in help. So these commands are not working for other reason.

Comment: Yes. `\\` was what I was trying to use (and it wasn't working). While the solution I accepted works foe me, I don't think it adresses the root cause of the problem, whatever that is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting your mapleader in your .vimrc:

```
let mapleader = ","
```